# The length of execution output is over limit (around 4MB currently)

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Calling Rest Api in webactivity using azure a=data factory. the activity fails with the error "The length of execution output is over limit (around 4MB currently)". Any solution for this??

Comment: Is the issue with the API or Data Factory? In other words: if you do *the same* request to the API from for instance Postman, does it work?

Comment: Not able to check from postman. And the same request giving authentication error while running on selfhosted IR.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this error is due to a hard limit (4MB) on the length of execution output.  Possible workaround is to restrict the size of the output or use [pagination](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/connector-rest#pagination-support) in the response.

But feel free to submit your feedback to ADF product team through ADF user voice forum. All the feedback shared in this forum are reviewed and monitored by ADF engineering team.

ADF feedback forum: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory

Please feel free reach us out in [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/products/azure?product=all) forum for such Azure product related queries.

Comment: There is no pagination concept in the attached page. Could you please add the reference to restrict size and pagination in web activity.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the link to Pagination support using REST connector not Web Activity.  I have also shared the feedback to ADF product team to update the public documentation to call out this limitation and possible workarounds.

Comment: Since your API response is more than 4 MB, if possible try to paginate your API results/response to make sure responses are easier to handle. REST connector in ADF supports pagination which can only be used if your API response is paginated.